# Unity3D XR InputFeatureUsage field not showing in inspector

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I want to customise the behaviour of my Oculus Quest controller when interacting with the touch controller. I have a script which detects when a button on a specific controller is pressed.

```
....
[Header ("Activation Controller")]
public XRNode controller = XRNode.RightHand;
public InputFeatureUsage<bool> activationButton = UnityEngine.XR.CommonUsages.primaryButton;
...
```

the script compiles but the `InputFeatureUsage` doesn't show in the inspector. I tried adding `[SerializeField]` but it doesn't work either.